# Dropdown selectByValue not working to select menu item

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksZpw.png)
I am able to find and click on element as follows:

```
WebElement clienttype = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon']"));
clienttype.click();
```

However, when I then try to select one of the menu items as follows:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(clienttype);
dropdown.selectByValue("PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS");
```

it simply bypasses and continues script running.  I have also tried selectByVisibleText and it doesn't work either.  Suggestions?

ADDING HTML...

```
    <span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">8 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
    <button tabindex="-1" title="" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" 
role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
```

**UPDATED HTML showing menu values >**

```
<div class="questionContainer ">
<div class="left questionBody" id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-label-body" required="false">
<label class="questionlabel bold " id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-label" for="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC">
Client Type:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    </div>
<div class="left answerBody">
        <div class="left">     
<div id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-answer-body">          
<div class="select_holder select_jquery">              
<select tabindex="0" id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC" aria-describedby="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-instructions" 
aria-labelledby="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-label" style="display: none;" required="true" level="0" autocomplete="off" 
responsetype="STATIC_MENU" questiondefid="QD005056A70C8E9da8UAyACwDA8EcC" totalorder="0" questionid="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC" val="" overwrite="1">                   
<option value=""></option>                                             
<option aria-selected="false" value="PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS" ps="0">PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS</option>                                               
<option aria-selected="false" value="Option 2" ps="1">Option 2</option>

<option aria-selected="false" value="Option 3" ps="2">Option 3</option>

<option aria-selected="false" value="Option 4 " ps="3">Option 4 </option>

<option aria-selected="false" value="Option 5" ps="4">Option 5</option>

<option aria-selected="false" value="Option 6" ps="5">Option 6</option>

<option aria-selected="false" value="Option 7" ps="6">Option 7r</option>

<option value="clear">(clear)</option>

</select><span><input class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC_input" autocomplete="off">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">8 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
<button tabindex="-1" title="" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text"></span></button></span>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="validationResult clear" id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-validationResult"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="instructions" id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-instructions"></div>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="no_dispaly" id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-rules"></div>

<div class="no_dispaly" id="QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC-json"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant `HTML` to your post as well as your code for getting the variable `dropdown`

Comment: Two things: first you need to define the object as a Select using the webelement. `Select drop = new Select(clienttype);` Also, you might be confusing "value" with text.  Unless the HTML code shows value tags with the options, you probably want to `drop.selectByVisibleText("PUBLIC-CUStOMERS");`

Comment: Also, there's no need to click on a dropdown when it's defined as a select.

Comment: @BillHileman I think that is just an example, the element in the click example is a button

Comment: Ah, you may be right.  The OP probably also did assign the webelement to a select but did not show the code for that, as I also now see the second section of code does use a different element name.

Comment: @BillHileman Yeah, it's hard to be sure without more info.

Comment: Have added HTML and select dropdown code as requested

Comment: @Terri I see a few issues. You are passing a button to the `new Select()` a button is not a `Select`. Also, the button does not have any children, so trying to set an option on that button is useless. Would you mind posting the HTML where this option exists: "PUBLIC-CUStOMERS"

Comment: @Ryan Wilson - The html is shown above.  The PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS is one of the 8 options shown in line 1 of the html if you scroll to the right.  Also, the button is what is clicked to show the menu items.  I'm trying to replicate what a tester does and they click that button which shows the menu items and then they select one of those items.

Comment: @Terri I scrolled and see no such thing

Comment: @Ryan Wilson - See "8 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</" on line 1 of the html code.

Comment: @Terri that isn't an option element with text "PUBLIC-CUStOMERS", so I still fail to see how you expect to set this value.

Comment: @Ryan - PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS is one of those 8 results available.  I tried to copy a screenshot here but it won't allow me to do so.  When I do inspect element on the page the above html is what I give.  No where do I see is listing out the actual 8 menu items.

Comment: The suggestion to create the select from the webelement was my mistake - I did not catch that your webelement was NOT a select tag, I incorrectly assumed that you were assigning a select to a webelement and missed a step, but as @RyanWilson pointed out, you were actually only pointing to the button.  There is no SELECT tag that we can see in the HTML code you provided, nor any OPTION tags.

Comment: I dug deeper in the inspect element code and have added the update (with the menu items) above.

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: My script needs to click a button that is a down-arrow and shows a menu.  That is working with code:  WebElement downarrow = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon']"));
downarrow.click();  Now I need to select one of the menu items that is shown but since its a button seems I cannot use Select.  What should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed a select type element. That was the problem why the selectByValue is not working.

The updated HTML you have posted has the select element.

For this page-source, pass the select element to the `new Select()` constructor. Then you can use the selectByValue method.

If the id is not generated dynamically then the `clienttype` variable should be:

```
WebElement clienttype = driver.findElement(By.id("QS005056A70C8E9da8UA3v-vDA7UcC"));
```

Otherwise:

```
WebElement clienttype = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.questionContainer > div.left.answerBody > div > div > div > select"));
```

Then you can use the following code:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(clienttype);
dropdown.selectByValue("PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS");
```

Comment: I tried the following and it is still not working:                                  WebElement clienttype = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon']"));
agency.click();
Select dropdown = new Select(clienttype);
dropdown.selectByValue("PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS");

Comment: If I use the following it will type the text in the field but once it moves to the next field this will null out.                                              driver.findElement(By.id("QS005056A70C8Ekte8UAemWyDAE14C_input")).sendKeys("PUBLIC-CUSTOMERS");

Comment: Every field on this web page that is a menu nulls out once it goes to the next field.  I watch it type the text in the field successfully yet it erases it once it moves to the next field.  Why would it erase it?

Comment: @Terri You are assigning a button element instead of the select element in the `clienttype` variable in your first example. And in the second example, I don't know how the input field is actually working with the select elements. Could you pelase attach a screenshot?  
You should try the css selector I've posted in the answer. It uses the select element and it should work with the selectByValue or selectByVisibleText.

Comment: @S Ahmed   I added a screenshot to the question as requested.

Comment: @S Ahmed   The down arrow shown to the right of each question is a button.  Once the menu is clicked on you should be able to select one of the menu values.  However, it is not working.  Therefore, I chose the 2nd option (find element/sendKeys).    The 2nd option works, typing in the value but once focus goes to the next menu it nulls out the value.  This only happens when the next field is a menu.  If the next field is another type of field (character, radio buttion, etc) it will keep the menu value.